# Caesar encryption with ASCII punctuation, digits, and uppercase letters?

Tags: python, caesar-cipher, punctuation

Trying to make caesar cipher function include ASCII uppercase, digits and punctuation instead of just lowercase.
so a sentence like "hello1?" pushed forward one key would turn into "ifmmp2@" because the ASCII punctuation list is in this order: !"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[]^_`{|}~

Here's my code so far:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase as letters
from string import punctuation
from string import digits

def encrypt(sentence, key):
    """
    key must be positive
    """
    print(f"Message: {sentence}")
    print(f"Key: {key}")
    enc = "".join(map(lambda x: ((2*letters)[letters.find(x) + key%len(letters)])
      ((2*punctuation)[punctuation.find(x) + key%len(punctuation)])
      ((2*digits)[digits.find(x) + key%len(digits)]) 
      if x in letters else x, sentence))
    print(f"Encrypt: {enc}\n")
    return enc

try:
    line = input().lower()
    key = int(input())
    assert key > 0
except:
    key = 5


secret = encrypt(line, key)
```

The error that pops up is the following:

```
raceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/arkan/Desktop/Code:Data Vizualization/Math/Cryptography/Caesar2.py", line 25, in <module>
    secret = encrypt(line, key)
  File "/Users/arkan/Desktop/Code:Data Vizualization/Math/Cryptography/Caesar2.py", line 11, in encrypt
    enc = "".join(map(lambda x: ((2*letters)[letters.find(x) + key%len(letters)])
  File "/Users/arkan/Desktop/Code:Data Vizualization/Math/Cryptography/Caesar2.py", line 11, in <lambda>
    enc = "".join(map(lambda x: ((2*letters)[letters.find(x) + key%len(letters)])
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Comment: Break up the line `enc = ...` into several lines. You're trying to do too much in one line which is why you cannot see where the error lies. I suggest a simple for loop instead of a list comprehension until you get the code right.

Comment: In the line with the error, `((2*letters)[letters.find(x) + key%len(letters)])` is being treated as a function with the argument `((2*punctuation)[punctuation.find(x) + key%len(punctuation)])` which in turn is being treateed as a function with the argument `((2*digits)[digits.find(x) + key%len(digits)])` all of which are strings, that's why the TypeError

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Corrected code:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase as letters
from string import punctuation
from string import digits

def encrypt(sentence, key):
    """
    key must be positive
    """
    print(f"Message: {sentence}")
    print(f"Key: {key}")
    enc = "".join(map(lambda x: (((2*letters)[letters.find(x) + key%len(letters)]) if x in letters else "" +
      ((2*punctuation)[punctuation.find(x) + key%len(punctuation)]) if x in punctuation else "" +
      ((2*digits)[digits.find(x) + key%len(digits)]) if x in digits else "" ), sentence))
    print(f"Encrypt: {enc}\n")
    return enc

try:
    line = input().lower()
    key = int(input())
    assert key > 0
except:
    key = 5


secret = encrypt(line, key)
```

I've checked it on my end it works!

Note: I like to write code in an obfuscated way too but when you're writing such a complicated piece of algorithm it is better to first write the code in a simple (possibly long) way, check if it works, then convert it into maps, list comprehensions and lambdas. Much easier to debug. These builtins are faster than the longer code, so it is better for the final product to be like that anyway.

Comment: Thanks Vedant36, but your corrected code still pops up with a ``` type error: 'str' object is not callable``` for me. Most people that I've seen make caesar cyphers do use maps, lambdas etc... and I feel as though I'm not knowledgeable enough to know how to make it the longer but simpler way. What I have been trying to do is expand on somebody else's code by including punctuation and digits.

Comment: my bad i copied the wrong code aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

Comment: @ArkLomas i put the correct code. Now it should work! Although I would suggest you to learn to read such obfuscated code.